How do I calculate average height and total height from a list using Python?
I am trying to calculate the total height and average height of students from a list.
student_heights = [120, 124, 165, 173, 189, 169, 146]

total_height = 0

for height in student_heights:
    print(height)


Why did you not add height to total_height using +? That would be the most intuitive thing to do.
